# Android Studio cannot resolve symbols for composite includeBuild dependency in java library submodule

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have an android project where the :app module uses a java library module :core which contains business logic and no android code. The :core module depends on a java library (Smack in my case) which I substituted by using gradle's composite build feature (includeBuild).

Building and running the app (both through AS as well as using gradle only) works like a charm, however Android Studio complains that Smack classes cannot be found in the :core module. So when coding in the :core module, I don't have auto completion and lots or warnings in the IDE. Hovering over Smack imports yields the error message 'Cannot resolve symbol'.
The dependency can be resolved from the :app module however.

AS suggests adding a project dependency on Smack, however this leads to gradle not being able to resolve it anymore. This is also not how I understood composite builds so far.

I suspect that AS mistakes Smack for an Android library somehow, so it only lets the :app module resolve it. What speaks for this theory is that if I change :core to be an android library resolving works as intended.

If I build a similar setup (without the android parts) in Intellij, everything works as expected.

I already tried using different gradle and gradle plugin versions in Android Studio, yet no success so far. Invalidaing caches and deleting the .AndroidStudioX.X directories didn't help either. Right now I'm running AS 3.6.3.

I also already tried manual substitution as [described here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_build_declaring_substitutions).

A minimal (not) working example for you to reproduce the issue can be [found here](https://codeberg.org/vanitasvitae/BrokenAndroidStudioCompositeBuild).

Any help is very welcome :)

Edit: Related Android Studio bug-tracker ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155690726

Edit: As a workaround I'm currently using Android Studio 3.5.3, which does not suffer from this issue.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Not yet. For now I downgraded to Android Studio 3.5.3, which does not suffer from this.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this with new AS? Thanks